# What java8 syntax is this and where can i read more?

Tags: lambda, java-8

How do you put multiple method calls (e.g 'get' in the below case) in a block?

```
package Routes;

import org.jooby.mvc.Path;

public class UserRoutes extends BaseRoutes {

  {

    get("/users", (req, resp) -> {
        resp.send("Uses index");
    });

    get("/user/:id", (req, resp) -> {
        resp.send("Single user page");
    });
  }

}
```

I am reading about lambdas and the documents talk about a single method interface. 
I am learning lambdas as i learn a web framework called [jooby](http://jooby.org)

Comment: What exactly confuses you in this code? If you're already learning about lambdas, then you should know that `(req, resp) -> { ... }` is indeed a lambda.

Comment: What confuses me is putting multiple methods in a block.

Comment: Ah. It's not multiple methods. It's multiple method calls. The instance initializer block (which you can see as a constructor block) simply contains multiple calls to the method get(). It allows defining two routes, by specigying their path, and what to do with the request and the response when a GET request comes to that path.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet, 'Initializer Block' is what i was looking for.  Now i know  what to read about. May be you can put your comment as an answer and i will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's called an `initializer block` that executes two methods `get`.

That `get` methods looks like take a `String` and a `BiConsumer` as input. Other than that not entirely sure what other syntax confuses u.

Comment: I had never heard of initializer block before today. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This construct has nothing to do with lambdas; has been around since Java 6 I believe.  The syntax is called an [initialization block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) or an [instance initializer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.6).   The code in-between the `{ }` is copied to every constructor in your class by the Java compiler. The block is also invoked when an instance of your class is created.  You can think of this as a better alternative to an "init" method that has to be called by every constructor.

Note that your `User` class is extending a base class where the `get` methods are apparently* defined.  You could alternatively write

```
{

    this.get("/users", (req, resp) -> {
        resp.send("Uses index");
    });

}
```

Or

```
import org.jooby.Jooby;

public class UserRoutes {    

    {
        Jooby jooby = new Jooby();

        jooby.get("/users", (req, resp) -> {
                resp.send("Uses index");
            });
    }
}
```

*Normally you would extend `org.jooby.Jooby`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Now i get it.